# flutter_blue_plus plugin in release mode for android doesn't always send or receive data

Tags: java, android, ios, flutter, dart

I built a bluetooth-based application and use the flutter_blue_plus plugin. The application is in debug mode and works without any problems. If I put it in release mode, different things happen, it doesn't always send or receive data. Of course, the problem is on Android, I haven't noticed any such problems on iOS.

I read the documentation carefully and added proguard-rules.pro in android/app/:

```
-keep class com.lib.flutter_blue_plus.* { *; }
```

and I added something like this in android/app/build.gradle:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        minifyEnabled false
        shrinkResources false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

The permissions I have added in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <!-- Tell Google Play Store that your app uses Bluetooth LE
     Set android:required="true" if bluetooth is necessary -->
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="false" />

    <!-- New Bluetooth permissions in Android 12
    https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/features/bluetooth-permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <!-- legacy for Android 11 or lower -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" android:maxSdkVersion="30" />

    <!-- legacy for Android 9 or lower -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" android:maxSdkVersion="28" />
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Add Bluetooth Permission to `AndroidManifest.xml` like bellow:

```
<!-- BLUETOOTH Permissions -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
```

Comment: I have added these permissions. I edited the post to see exactly what permissions I have added.

Comment: are you getting any error or warnings in console?

Comment: no, because when I upload the application from the computer, i.e. the debug version. So I don't have any errors in the console. If I build the application as: flutter build-apk and install it on the phone as an .apk file, then I have problems

Comment: use logcat in android studio

Comment: OK thanks. I'll try to do it and come back with information